# Bootstrap carousel not resetting on page return

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple carousel that isn't doing anything crazy. I would like it to reset on page load, no matter how I get to that page. Here's my process...

1) Click on carousel tab - carousel slides to that slide.

2) Click on link and go to new page.

3) Click "back arrow" and the carousel has not rest.

**However**

1) Click on carousel tab - carousel slides to that slide.

2) Click on link and go to new page.

3) Click on original page through navigation, carousel has reset.

```
$('.carousel.graph').carousel({
    pause: true,
    interval: false
}).carousel(0);
```

Has anybody else run into this glitch? I can't figure out how to fix it.

**Note:**  I'm using v.3

Comment: When do you start your carousel ?

Comment: it doesn't rotate automatically, the user has to click on links.

Comment: On page load you should be able to call the carousel and choose where it starts.